# If we assume constant Temperature and Pressure, why isn't the Change in Gibbs Free Energy always 0?

Tags: thermodynamics

The Gibbs Free Energy is defined as:

$$G = U + PV - TS$$

If we assume that the temperature $T$ and the Pressure $P$ are constant, then any change in the Gibbs Free Energy would be:

$$\Delta G = \Delta U + P \Delta V - T \Delta S$$

The First Law of Thermodynamics says $U = W + Q$, where $Q$ is any heat flow into the system and $W$ is work done on the system.  Therefore:

$$\Delta G = W + Q + P \Delta V - T \Delta S$$

We can also distinguish between work that expands/contracts the system and "other" work: $W = W_{expansion} + W_{other}$

We also know that any increase/decrease in the entropy of the system is due to either heat flow into/out of the system or "other" work performed on a system: $T \Delta S = Q + W_{other}$. (Expansion/contraction work does not increase/decrease the entropy of the system since any increase/decrease in the entropy due to added/removed energy is balanced by a decrease/increase in the entropy due to decreased/increase volume.)

Combining these two insights, we get:

$$\Delta G = W_{expansion} + W_{other} + Q + P \Delta V - (Q + W_{other})$$

And since $W_{expansion} = -P \Delta V$, we get:

$$\Delta G = -P \Delta V + W_{other} + Q + P \Delta V - Q - W_{other}$$

$$\Delta G = 0$$

(All terms cancel each other out.)

If this were true, the Gibbs Free Energy would be constant for a constant temperature and pressure change.  But this clearly can't be right, since it is commonly known that the Gibbs Free Energy tries to minimize itself in these situations.

Yet on the surface, it appears to be true: By its definition, any increase/decrease in the system's energy means that the $\Delta U$ term gets larger, but is balanced by a decrease/increase in the $T \Delta S$ term, unless the energy increase/decrease comes from contraction/expansion, in which case it would be balanced by a decrase/increase in the $P \Delta V$ term.

So where is the mistake?

Comment: "We also know that any increase/decrease in the entropy of the system is due to either heat flow into/out of the system or "other" work performed on a system:" This is part you need to rethink. What makes you say that? Even an isolated system, with no heat or work applied, can increase its entropy. (The whole universe is such a system, after all).

Comment: @DominicElse I guess in the case of the whole universe, I would say that the assumption of constant temperature does not hold.  And I suppose if I did wait around long enough until the temperature was constant, then I guess I really could legitimately claim that the universe can't increase its entropy.

Comment: Perhaps the whole universe wasn't a good example as it's not really in thermal equilibrium. But it is possible for an isolated system to increase its entropy. Think about releasing a partition to allow two different species of gas molecules (previously kept separate) to mix together, for example. Entropy change is not something that can be determined just from interactions with the environment (except in reversible processes -- but the process by which a system changes its Gibbs free energy is *not* reversible).

Comment: If chemical reaction is occurring within the system, even if the temperature and pressure are constant, U, S, H, and G all change.  These changes are the result of making and breaking chemical bonds.

Comment: You're confusing the Legendre transformation from $U=U(S,V,N_{1},N_{2},..)$ to the Gibbs potential after eliminating $U,S,$ and $V$ - which yields $G=G(T,P,N_{1},N_{2})$. What is it you're trying to calculate? There are other potentials - pick one which is useful.

Comment: I don't know what a Legendre transformation from U to G is so it's hard for me to respond.  All I'm doing is taking to its logical conclusion that 1) $G = U + PV -TS$, 2) $U = Q + W$  3) $W = W_{expansion} + W_{other}$, 4) $W_{expansion} = -P \Delta V$, 5) $T \Delta S = Q + W_{other}$.  I'm getting an answer this is wrong, but I don't know where the error is. @CinaedSimson

Comment: Okay, it doesn't matter about the Legendre transformation. If you're using $\Delta G$ at constant temperate and pressure, then you're most likely using the wrong potential - one expects $\Delta G=0$ under those conditions. The error is you don't have a problem - it's just hand waving - the devil is in the detail - your doesn't have a physical problem. The error is most likely in the signs of $\Delta S$, $\Delta V$, and $W$.

Comment: The thing is, the thermodynamics textbook that I am reading specifically states (and sort of derives) that if temperature and pressure are constant than $\Delta G \le W_{other}$, yet here you and I are agreeing that in this situation $\Delta G = 0$ .  The textbook is Thermal Physics by Daniel Schroeder.  @CinaedSimson